# Assuming $a,k \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $(a-1)(a+1)=3k$ then why is it true that either $3|(a-1)$ or $3|(a+1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I was working on this problem:

> Let $a$ be an integer. Prove $a$ is not evenly divisible by $3$ if and only if $a^2-1$ is evenly divisible by $3$.

I figured out how to prove the first statement, "if $3 \nmid a$ then $3|(a^2-1)$" by considering the cases where $a\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $a\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$.

However, when I got to the converse, "if $3|(a^2-1)$ then $3\nmid a$" I got stuck, so I checked the solution manual for a hint, and it did the following to start out proving the converse:

> Since $a^2-1$ is evenly divisible by $3$, then $a^2-1=3k,\exists k\in \mathbb{Z}$.
> Then $\color{red}{(a-1)(a+1)=3k\implies 3|(a-1)\: \text{or} \: 3|(a+1)}$.

After this, it proceeds to consider the cases where $3|(a-1)$ and $3|(a+1)$ to prove the statement. I just don't understand how we know the implication I've highlighted in red is true.

Comment: Also, now that I think about it, it may be more efficient to prove the converse using the contrapositive, "if $3|a$ then $3 \nmid (a^2-1)$" rather than this technique.

Comment: (just tried it. it is. lol)

Comment: Because $3$ is prime, it divides a product $(a-1)(a+1)$ iff it divides one of the factors of that product.

Comment: Special case $\,p=3\,$ in Euclid's Lemma - see the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct result of [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma):

- If $a$ and $b$ are integers and $p$ is prime such that $p | ab$, then either $p | a$ or $p | b$ (or both).

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't see the dupe tag when I answered but I will keep an eye out in future.